# Why char array and int array get printed as different things?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, c++11

```
int main ()
{
    int intarr [5] = {1,6,7,9,3);
    char charr [7] = "Avneet";
    std::cout << intarr << "\n";
    std::cout << charr << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

The first line this program prints is a memory address and second line, the whole string (Avneet). What's making the difference? One more question. In the int case, the address I get is what? The address of the entire array or just the address of the first element of that array.

Answer (score 4):

`std::basic_ostream<>` has overloads of [`operator<<`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) for `char const*` and signed/unsigned versions that expect a C-style zero-terminated string.

And `void const*` overload which is used for any other pointer types and outputs the address.

Answer (score 1):

The `std::cout` operator `<<` is overloaded for `const char*` in such a way that the string that it points to is printed out. This is not the case for `int*` arguments.

When an array is passed (by value) as an argument to a function the argument decays to a pointer to the first element in the array and that is why you get the behaviour you are seeing - the `char` array argument decays to `char*` and the `cout` operator `<<` overload prints the string.

In the `int*` case there is no overload and so you just see the address of the first element of your `int` array printed.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that when creating a char[7] it acts like a String of 7 characters. When printing that will not show its address but the value.

On the other hand the int array is an object which holds some primitives. When printing it you will simply see that objects address. You need a for loop to print each of the arrays elements.